# MySQL count rows where another column = value

Tags: mysql, count

I have a `While` loop that displays the `COUNT` of `p.songid` (post tracks) in each row. What I actually need is to get the count based on `trackDeleted=0` instead of all the rows.

```
 SELECT u.username, u.id, u.score, s.genre, s.songid, s.songTitle, s.timeSubmitted, s.userid, s.insWanted, s.bounty, COUNT(p.songid)
 FROM  songs s
 LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = s.userid
 LEFT JOIN posttracks p ON s.songid = p.songid
 WHERE paid=1 AND s.timeSubmitted >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY )
 GROUP BY s.timeSubmitted ASC
 LIMIT 25
```

Can I update the above query or does this have to be in a separate query?

Comment: Where is the WHILE loop?  In mysql or a server-side programming language?

Comment: The WHILE loop is in PHP

Comment: So you are counting all rows of p.songid in the query above by looping through and incrementing a count variable in PHP??

Comment: Yes, this query loops through in PHP for every row of p.songid.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this works in mySql but in SQL you are able to filter during the join as follows:

```
SELECT u.username, u.id, u.score, s.genre, s.songid, s.songTitle, s.timeSubmitted, s.userid, s.insWanted, s.bounty, COUNT(p.songid)
FROM  songs s
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = s.userid
LEFT JOIN posttracks p ON s.songid = p.songid and trackDeleted=0
WHERE paid=1 AND s.timeSubmitted >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY )
GROUP BY s.timeSubmitted ASC
LIMIT 25
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends in what table the trackDeleted column is.

If it lives in posttracks, then it's simple

```
SELECT COUNT(p.songid) FROM posttracks p where p.trackDeleted=0
```

Comment: I re-phrased my question.  I need to COUNT all the rows called songid where trackdeleted (which is in p.posttracks) = 0.  Is this possible?

Comment: When I add this to the WHERE clause of my query it only returns tracks that have trackDeleted=0.  I need it to COUNT all tracks WHERE tracksDeleted=0

Comment: AND THAT IS WHAT IT'S DOING. SELECT --Projection-- COUNT(p.songid) --will count every row that p.songid is not null-- FROM posttracks p --this table, p is the alias-- where --condition-- p.tracksDeleted=0

Comment: BTW, if you need to count all tracks then the condition wouln't exist. You don't need to count all tracks, you need to count the tracks where trackDeleted=0.

Answer (score 0):

Add `trackDeleted = 0` to your `WHERE` clause:

```
...
WHERE paid=1 AND s.timeSubmitted >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY )
    AND trackDeleted=0
 --  ^^^ add this
GROUP BY s.timeSubmitted ASC
...
```

Comment: I re-phrased my question.  I need to COUNT all the rows called songid where trackdeleted (which is in p.posttracks) = 0.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
    You must group by the p.songid.

```
 SELECT u.username, u.id, u.score, s.genre, s.songid, s.songTitle,
 s.timeSubmitted, s.userid, s.insWanted, s.bounty, COUNT(p.songid) FROM
 songs s LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = s.userid LEFT JOIN posttracks p ON
 s.songid = p.songid WHERE paid=1 AND s.timeSubmitted >= ( CURDATE() -
 INTERVAL 60 DAY ) GROUP BY s.timeSubmitted ASC,p.songid LIMIT 25
```

Comment: I re-phrased my question. I need to COUNT all the rows called songid where trackdeleted (which is in p.posttracks) = 0. Is this possible?

Comment: yah!!just add in your condition the p.trackDeleted=0.

Comment: When I add this to the WHERE clause of my query it only returns tracks that have trackDeleted=0. I need it to COUNT all tracks WHERE tracksDeleted=0

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to COUNT the song id, you must group it by it self, try this one.

```
 SELECT u.username, u.id, u.score, s.genre, s.songid, s.songTitle, s.timeSubmitted, s.userid, s.insWanted, s.bounty, COUNT(p.songid)
   FROM  songs s
   LEFT JOIN users u
     ON u.id = s.userid
   LEFT JOIN posttracks p
     ON s.songid = p.songid
  WHERE paid=1 
    AND s.timeSubmitted >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY )
    AND trackDeleted=0
  GROUP BY p.songid
  ORDER BY s.timeSubmitted
  LIMIT 25;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either put your test in the join condition:

```
LEFT JOIN posttracks p
    ON s.songid = p.songid
    AND trackDeleted = 0
```

Or change `COUNT(p.songid)` to a SUM instead:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (p.songid IS NOT NULL AND trackDeleted = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone stumbles on this, as I did, the correct answer is probably something like:

```
SELECT u.username, u.id, u.score, s.genre, s.songid, s.songTitle, s.timeSubmitted, s.userid, s.insWanted, s.bounty, COUNT(IF(p.trackDeleted=0, 1, NULL)) as not_deleted_count
     FROM  songs s
     LEFT JOIN users u
     ON u.id = s.userid
     LEFT JOIN posttracks p
     ON s.songid = p.songid
     WHERE paid=1 AND s.timeSubmitted >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY )
     GROUP BY s.timeSubmitted ASC
     LIMIT 25
```

The key being `COUNT(IF(p.trackDeleted=0, 1, NULL)) as not_deleted_count` which will look at all the tracks in a grouping, and only count those that are not deleted.

Every other answer in here was mistaking the OP as only wanting to select tracks that werent deleted, when what he wanted was to count the number of tracks that werent deleted inside each grouping.

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
DECLARE @trackCount int,
SELECT u.username, u.id, u.score, s.genre, s.songid, s.songTitle, s.timeSubmitted, s.userid, s.insWanted, s.bounty,
 FROM songs s 
 LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = s.userid 
 LEFT JOIN posttracks p ON s.songid = p.songid 
 WHERE paid=1 
 AND s.timeSubmitted >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY)
 GROUP BY s.timeSubmitted ASC
 LIMIT 25

 SELECT COUNT(p.songid) INTO @TrackCount
 FROM posttracks p
 WHERE p.trackDeleted = 0
```

try to add this to your code. just access local variable @trackcount if you need to show how many tracks have trackDeleted = 0.

Comment: I re-phrased my question.  I need to COUNT all the rows called songid where trackdeleted (which is in p.posttracks) = 0.  Is this possible?

Comment: @Nathan, you do not declare `@vars`, they just are; `@trackcount = count(*)` is incorrect it should be `SELECT @trackcount:= count(*) FROM ....` or `SELECT count(*) INTO @trackcount FROM ....`

Comment: thanks for the insight! Still new to programming so I may have named some, if not all of my codes in a bad way. Thanks!